# ConnectionRefusedError exception when running Autobahn rpc example

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn

I'm trying to run [AutobahnPython slowsquare rpc example](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/wamp/basic/rpc/slowsquare/backend.py) in python with no much luck.

When running the above script i'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\src\twisted-test\rpc_server.py", line 39, in <module>
    runner.run(Component)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\autobahn\twisted\wamp.py", line 245, in run
    raise connect_error.exception
twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..
```

I dont have much experience with twisted / Autobahn and websockets in general and i'm a bit stuck. The other examples i've tried using web socket are working perfectly.

I'm using python 2.7 on windows 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that the developer of Autobahn framework recommended the following:

```
pip install crossbar
cd $HOME/mynode
crossbar init
crossbar start
```

Here is the thread about your problem: [autobahn google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autobahnws/5NSAv0Clhjc)